# Probability of first to win n matches and score distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A game is played between two players. Winning a single game gives one point. The probability of winning a single game is P and losing is S=1-P.
If this game is played until a player wins N times what is the probability of winning depending on N, P and S?

I have tried to calculate this but only managed to 4 see below. not sure if it is correct but believe so. I would like to have the answer in the same format for larger N up to 10 or if possible generally for N.

N=1: P

N=2: P^2 * ( 1 + 2*S )

N=3: P^3 * ( 1 + 3*S + 4*S^2 )

N=4: P^4 * ( 1 + 4*S + 10*S^2 + 20*S^3 )

The above format is informative regarding the distribution of scores and their probability

Answer (score 1):

I will change your notation a bit to conform to general practice, so that
the probability of winning a single game is $p$ and losing is $q=1-p$.

A player wins with exactly $n$ games if and only if s(he) wins the last one; also, the other player can win $k$ games,  $ k = 0\;\; thru\;\; (n-1)$ games.

The $(n-1)$ wins before the last  can thus be interspersed in $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$ ways

For $n=4$, e.g., $Pr = p^4[\binom33 + \binom43q + \binom53q^2 + \binom63q^3]$

You should now be able to put it in a general formula, and work out for any $n$

Btw, for $n=3$, there is an error in your calculations.
It should be $p^3[\binom22 + \binom32q + \binom42q^2] = p^3(1+3q +6q^2)$